# Вопрос про pthreads PHP на Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu

http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pthreads.php

Все пишут что это очень просто, но на деле получается немного сложнее.

Как рекомпилировать (recompile) php, и затем (если я правильно понимаю) поставить его в систему. И получается до этого нужно удалить все php-* подобные части из системы.

Есть ли готовый для установки php пакет вместе с pthreads?

Comment: *получается до этого нужно удалить все php-\* подобные части из системы.* - зачем, просто поставьте его в /opt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
pecl install pthreads-1.0.0
```

Если у вас возникает такая ошибка:

```
checking for ZTS... configure: error: pthreads requires ZTS, 
please re-compile PHP with ZTS enabled
```

То вам нужно установить PHP с ZTS [из любого подходящего PPA с вашей версией PHP](https://www.google.ru/search?q=ubuntu%20php%20zts%20ppa) (версия не указана в вопросе)